# Deep XML dozer mapping issue

Tags: dozer

i have an issue with xml dozer mapping, either it is not supporting this kind of deep mapping or i made something wrong.
the source is :

```
Public Class ABean{
private List<AABean> aa;
}

Public Class AABean{
private List<BBean> b;
}

Public Class BBean{
private List<String> c;
}
```

the destination is:

```
Public Class A{
private List<AA> aa;
}

Public Class AA{
private List<B> b;
}

Public Class B{
private List<String> c;
}
```

mapping was:

```
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
          http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">

     <mapping type="one-way" date-format="MM/dd/yyyy" stop-on-errors="false" map-null="false"  map-empty-string="false">
    <class-a>sourcePackage.ABean</class-a>
    <class-b>disPackage.A</class-b>
    <field>
    <a>aa</a>
    <b>aa</b>
    <a-hint>sourcePackage.AABean</a-hint>
    <b-hint>disPackage.AA</b-hint>
    </field>

<field>
    <a>aa</a>
    <b>aa</b>
    <a-hint>sourcePackage.aa</a-hint>
    <b-hint>disPackage.aa</b-hint>
    </field>
    </mapping>

    <mapping type="one-way" date-format="MM/dd/yyyy" stop-on-errors="true" map-null="false"  map-empty-string="false">
<class-a>sourcePackage.aa</class-a>
<class-b>disPackage.aa</class-b>
    <field>
    <a>b</a>
    <b>b</b>
    <a-hint>sourcePackage.BBean</a-hint>
    <b-hint>disPackage.B</b-hint>
    </field>
    </mapping>
<mapping type="one-way" date-format="MM/dd/yyyy" stop-on-errors="true" map-null="false"  map-empty-string="false">
    <class-a>sourcePackage.BBean</class-a>
    <class-b>disPackage.B</class-b>
    <field>
    <a>c</a>
    <b>c</b>
    </field>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

the bean list AABean has a value but after the mapping the AA is null, i tried to go deep in mapping by using dot in the first mapping but didn't work also,
please any one can help me

Answer (score 0):

mapping should work with the simple ABean to A mapping

```
    <mapping map-id="ray">
    <class-a>packare.ABean</class-a>
    <class-b>package.A</class-b>
</mapping>
```

Comment: i am doing the same, check my mapping. it start working suddenly. after four days, the mapping start not working while i did not touch the mapping